# Different results in gaussian smoothing when filtering in time / frequency domain

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm implementing a gaussian smoothing filter on c++ by point wise multiplication in frequency space. To check that my results were correct, I implemented the same code in matlab and compared it to matlab's built in filtering function.

Here's the check:

```
% Gauss kernel, sigma = 1.
gaussfilter = fspecial('gaussian',[11 11], 1);

% Test matrix
testmatrix = ones(11);
testmatrix(6,6) = 5;

% FFT, pointwise multiplication in freq. space, and reverse FFT
testmatrix1 = fftshift(fftn(ifftshift(testmatrix),[]));
testmatrix1 = testmatrix1 .* gaussfilter;
testmatrix1 = fftshift(ifftn(ifftshift(testmatrix1),[],'nonsymmetric'));

abs(testmatrix1) % expect equal to c++

% Check that matlab is doing the same..
testmatrix2 = imfilter(testmatrix, gaussfilter);

abs(testmatrix2) % expect equal to testmatrix1
```

To my surprise, I see that matlab's `imfilter` is returning something different. `testmatrix2` is not the same as `testmatrix1`.

Why should this be the case? Is there something wrong with my understanding of filters, or am I calling imfilter incorrectly? (flagging `imfilter` with `'replicate'`, or `'conv'` doesn't solve my problem).

Here are both matrices:

testmatrix1 =

```
0.1592    0.1592    0.1593    0.1595    0.1597    0.1598    0.1597    0.1595    0.1593    0.1592    0.1592
0.1592    0.1593    0.1597    0.1604    0.1612    0.1616    0.1612    0.1604    0.1597    0.1593    0.1592
0.1593    0.1597    0.1609    0.1631    0.1656    0.1668    0.1656    0.1631    0.1609    0.1597    0.1593
0.1595    0.1604    0.1631    0.1681    0.1738    0.1764    0.1738    0.1681    0.1631    0.1604    0.1595
0.1597    0.1612    0.1656    0.1738    0.1830    0.1872    0.1830    0.1738    0.1656    0.1612    0.1597
0.1598    0.1616    0.1668    0.1764    0.1872    0.1922    0.1872    0.1764    0.1668    0.1616    0.1598
0.1597    0.1612    0.1656    0.1738    0.1830    0.1872    0.1830    0.1738    0.1656    0.1612    0.1597
0.1595    0.1604    0.1631    0.1681    0.1738    0.1764    0.1738    0.1681    0.1631    0.1604    0.1595
0.1593    0.1597    0.1609    0.1631    0.1656    0.1668    0.1656    0.1631    0.1609    0.1597    0.1593
0.1592    0.1593    0.1597    0.1604    0.1612    0.1616    0.1612    0.1604    0.1597    0.1593    0.1592
0.1592    0.1592    0.1593    0.1595    0.1597    0.1598    0.1597    0.1595    0.1593    0.1592    0.1592
```

testmatrix2 =

```
0.4893    0.6585    0.6963    0.6994    0.6995    0.6995    0.6995    0.6994    0.6963    0.6585    0.4893
0.6585    0.8863    0.9371    0.9413    0.9416    0.9417    0.9416    0.9413    0.9371    0.8863    0.6585
0.6963    0.9371    0.9910    0.9963    0.9997    1.0025    0.9997    0.9963    0.9910    0.9371    0.6963
0.6994    0.9413    0.9963    1.0114    1.0521    1.0860    1.0521    1.0114    0.9963    0.9413    0.6994
0.6995    0.9416    0.9997    1.0521    1.2342    1.3861    1.2342    1.0521    0.9997    0.9416    0.6995
0.6995    0.9417    1.0025    1.0860    1.3861    1.6366    1.3861    1.0860    1.0025    0.9417    0.6995
0.6995    0.9416    0.9997    1.0521    1.2342    1.3861    1.2342    1.0521    0.9997    0.9416    0.6995
0.6994    0.9413    0.9963    1.0114    1.0521    1.0860    1.0521    1.0114    0.9963    0.9413    0.6994
0.6963    0.9371    0.9910    0.9963    0.9997    1.0025    0.9997    0.9963    0.9910    0.9371    0.6963
0.6585    0.8863    0.9371    0.9413    0.9416    0.9417    0.9416    0.9413    0.9371    0.8863    0.6585
0.4893    0.6585    0.6963    0.6994    0.6995    0.6995    0.6995    0.6994    0.6963    0.6585    0.4893
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.
I just had to take the FFT of `gaussfilter` before multiplying it with `testmatrix1`, and pass the flag `'replicate'` to `imfilter`.

Changes:

```
testmatrix1 = testmatrix1 .* fftshift(fftn(ifftshift(gaussfilter),[]));
```

and

```
testmatrix2 = imfilter(testmatrix, gaussfilter,'replicate');
```